# Problems with linking MATLAB and Visual Studios

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab, linker-errors, unresolved-external

In my on my header file (pages.h), I've done:

```
#include "mat.h".
```

In my cpp, all I'm trying to do is a simple:

```
MATFile *pmat.
```

However, whenever I try to build my code, I get an error that says:

```
1>pages.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _matOpen referenced in function "public: void __thiscall DataPage::LoadDBIData(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?LoadDBIData@DataPage@@QAEXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
```

and

```
1>C:\Users\celes\source\repos\bci2000-svn\tools\P300Classifier_electrode_selection\P300Classifier_electrode_selection.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I've tried going into Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories and adding a file path of C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\extern\include", but I am still receiving the same error.  Without this included path, I only received the second error, not the first one.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (it's for an old research lab) and R2015b for MATLAB.

Any sort of help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you forgot to link to a library for matlib in your c++ project.

Comment: Yeah, I actually did get an error where they said I was missing libmat.dll, but I think that was related to my not downloading some tools.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the compiler has trouble resolving the symbol. Apparently, you didn't set up the project correctly. Besides the "Additional Include Directories" option, you also need to set the library directory in the **`Linker-> Additional Library Directories`** for using an external library.

Because you are running a project in VS C++, you will need to have `$(MATLABPATH)\extern\lib\<arch>\microsoft` in that option, where `$(MATLABPATH)` is **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b"** and the `<arch>` might be Win64 or Win32 depending on your target machine flag in your VS project (i.e. 32- or 64-bit).

Comment: Thank you for this!  This, combined with the comment above, helped to solve my issue :).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could check if you add `C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\extern\include` in `Porperties->VC++ Directories-> Include Directories`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2015b\extern\lib\winXX\microsoft` in `Porperties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories`.

Secondly, you could check if you add `libmat.lib;ibeng.lib;libmx.lib` in `Porperties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.

Finally, you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [LNK2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019) and [LNK1120](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1120?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thank you!  I think there were a few issues: I was missing some tools (I ended up adding all of them just in case), I needed the library directory you listed, and I was also missing the Additional Library Directory from the comment below.